# How to select all values with latest dates Laravel 5.8

Tags: date, laravel-5, select, eloquent

I am trying to get all of the rows with the latest dates

[image]

**I want to get the rows 3 and 4 only**

When I use this `eloquent` query:

```
    $items = Purchase::whereYear('created_at', '=', $year)
          ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $month)
          ->where('created_at', Purchase::max('created_at'))
          ->get();
    return $items;
```

Yet this is what I get:

> [{"id":4,"itemid":1,"price":"1.60","quantity":4,"created_at":"2019-09-14 08:39:31","updated_at":"2019-09-14 08:39:31"}]

Comment: your query is right. I think The information in the database is not what you think. Check the information again.

Answer (score 0):

You must be use `->whereDate()` function

```
$lastDate = Purchase::max('created_at')->format('Y-m-d');
$items = Purchase::whereDate('created_at', $lastDate)->get();
```

Edit:

```
$lastDate = Carbon::parse(Purchase::max('created_at'))->format('Y-m-d');
$items = Purchase::whereDate('created_at', $lastDate)->get();
```

Comment: this returns an error: `Call to a member function format() on string`